# Is this a correct usage of let function?

Tags: android, kotlin

currently learning android development (Kotlin).

i wonder if it's a correct usage of let function.

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = RetrofitHelper.getRealEstateService().getRealEstateModel()
        response.body()?.let {
            if(response.isSuccessful){
                val data = response.body()
                _data.emit(data?.content?: emptyList())
            }
        }
    }
```

previously i was checking if the value is null in a normal way like this:

```
if(response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null){
            val data = response.body()
            _data.emit(data?.content?: emptyList())
        }
```

so i just changed null check with let function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common pattern for dealing with nulls, however, it probably makes more sense to use parameter passed to `let` lambda, as it already contains a non-nullable response body:

```kotlin
response.body()?.let { data ->
    if(response.isSuccessful){
        _data.emit(data.content?: emptyList())
    }
}
```

This way we don't have to acquire `body()` twice and then deal with nullable value. If the `content` property of body is not nullable, then it becomes even simpler:

```kotlin
_data.emit(data.content)
```

Comment: Yeah, `let` basically creates a variable *for you*, using the current value of `response.body()`. And because you're using `?` to null-check it, the `let` block only runs if that variable is non-null - so inside the block, you have a variable that's cast to a non-null type, because it's been checked! That variable's called `it` by default, but *broot*'s example shows how you can rename it to `data` (like the variable you created yourself in your code)

Comment: thanks! after that studio suggested that i could remove elvis operator and the :emptyList()) in this code `_data.emit(data.content?: emptyList())`

can you please clarify that too?

Comment: @მიშოციციშვილი Ah, yes, if `content` property is itself not nullable, then it can be simplified even further. I updated my answer.

Comment: For data.content?: emptyList()  ?:  this is called Elvis operator if data.content is null than emptyList() would be returned otherwise content returned.